# Strategies to improve performance while traversing Github like tree

Tags: javascript, reactjs

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/devbox/react-router-dom-example-forked-qz3kl3?file=%2Fpackage.json%3A12%2C34&layout=%257B%2522sidebarPanel%2522%253A%2522EXPLORER%2522%252C%2522rootPanelGroup%2522%253A%257B%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522ROOT_LAYOUT%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522UNKNOWN%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00063b6gxhkoygaz%2522%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B70%252C30%255D%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522EDITOR%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00023b6gs4b0gfxm%2522%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522horizontal%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522SHELLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00043b6gi38b8pe1%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL_GROUP%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522direction%2522%253A%2522vertical%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522panels%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522PANEL%2522%252C%2522contentType%2522%253A%2522DEVTOOLS%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00053b6g2q3s5og6%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B100%255D%257D%255D%252C%2522sizes%2522%253A%255B40%252C60%255D%257D%252C%2522tabbedPanels%2522%253A%257B%2522clttypxin00023b6gs4b0gfxm%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00023b6gs4b0gfxm%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttzg3wb00023b6gp5p5ldum%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A18%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A29%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A18%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A29%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fsrc%252FGitHubTree.jsx%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522cltzfkxoa00023b6h18kvmkjs%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522FILE%2522%252C%2522initialSelections%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522startLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522startColumn%2522%253A34%252C%2522endLineNumber%2522%253A12%252C%2522endColumn%2522%253A34%257D%255D%252C%2522filepath%2522%253A%2522%252Fpackage.json%2522%252C%2522state%2522%253A%2522IDLE%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522cltzfkxoa00023b6h18kvmkjs%2522%257D%252C%2522clttypxin00053b6g2q3s5og6%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00053b6g2q3s5og6%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_PORT%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522port%2522%253A5173%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttyq8ay00a83b6geunleqdi%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522path%2522%253A%2522%252Ftree%252FParent1%252FChild11%252FChild111%252Ffile.png%2522%257D%255D%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clttyq8ay00a83b6geunleqdi%2522%257D%252C%2522clttypxin00043b6gi38b8pe1%2522%253A%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00043b6gi38b8pe1%2522%252C%2522activeTabId%2522%253A%2522clttyq43u008m3b6g3krjp8bh%2522%252C%2522tabs%2522%253A%255B%257B%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttypxin00033b6g8y9jny60%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%252C%2522type%2522%253A%2522TERMINAL%2522%252C%2522shellId%2522%253A%2522clttypy30001bdbf804m23uj1%2522%257D%252C%257B%2522type%2522%253A%2522TASK_LOG%2522%252C%2522taskId%2522%253A%2522Development%2522%252C%2522id%2522%253A%2522clttyq43u008m3b6g3krjp8bh%2522%252C%2522mode%2522%253A%2522permanent%2522%257D%255D%257D%257D%252C%2522showDevtools%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showShells%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522showSidebar%2522%253Atrue%252C%2522sidebarPanelSize%2522%253A15%257D) I am trying to represent Github tree like structure. Every time an element is clicked I traverse the entire tree to find the children of that parent. Can someone please suggest a better way(**improve performance**) to do this.

```
  import React from "react";
import { gitTreeData } from "./gitTreeData";
import { Link, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";
import { Route, Routes } from "react-router-dom";
import FileViewer from "react-file-viewer";

const GitHubTree = () => {
  let { state } = useLocation();

  const { parentName, childLevel, filePath, fileType } = state || {};

  const renderTreeRoot = () => {
    if (filePath) {
      return <FileViewer fileType={fileType} filePath={filePath} />;
    }
    return gitTreeData.map((child) => {
      if ((!childLevel && !child.parent) || child.parent === parentName) {
        if (child.type === "file") {
          return (
            <Link
              key={child.id}
              state={{
                parentName: child.name,
                childLevel: Number(child.level) + 1,
                filePath: child.path,
                fileType: child.fileType,
              }}
              to={`${child.name}`}
            >
              <li key={child.id}>{child.name}</li>
            </Link>
          );
        }
        return (
          <Link
            key={child.id}
            state={{
              parentName: child.name,
              childLevel: Number(child.level) + 1,
            }}
            to={`${child.name}`}
          >
            <li key={child.id}>{child.name}</li>
          </Link>
        );
      }
      return null;
    });
  };
  return (
    <Routes>
      <Route index element={renderTreeRoot()} />
      <Route path=":parentName/*" element={<GitHubTree />} />
    </Routes>
  );
};

export default GitHubTree;
```